# What are the worst forms of poetry in the universe?

Tags: the-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-galaxy

In the context of Douglas Adams's [*Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy), if Vogon poetry is “the third worst poetry in the universe”, then what is the second worst and worst?

Comment: I'm not sure that we need an extra "vogon" tag.  Maybe after we have a few more vogon questions, but that doesn't seem likely for a long time.

Comment: I don't understand this question. The answer is in the book directly after the quote mentioned above...?

Comment: Just continue reading the rest of the paragraph.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The Wikipedia page on [Vogon Poetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogon#Poetry) quotes the book:

> The second worst is that of the Azgoths of Kria. [...] The very worst poetry in the universe died along with its creator, [Paula Nancy Millstone Jennings of Sussex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_minor_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy_characters#Paul_Neil_Milne_Johnstone)... in the destruction of the planet Earth.

[Note](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogon#cite_note-1): The name mentioned in the original radio series was *Paul Neil Milne Johnstone of Redbridge, Essex*, but this was later removed due to his complaint.

Comment: GAH!  You can't answer it like that!  You can't cut out parts!

Comment: Yes, it cuts DNA's wonderful humor.  But it is the correct answer, without any "fluff".  Yi *does* link to the full quote on Wikipedia, so nothing is lost.

Comment: The wiki contains a sample of the very worst poetry. Be warned, it's (very) possibly nsfw. Or for not-work, for the matter.

Comment: I'm sure I'm not the only one - when I read this I hear it in Peter Jones' voice!

Answer (score 18):

> Vogon poetry is the third worst in the
>   Universe. The second worst is that of
>   the Azgoths of Kria. During a
>   recitation by their Poet Master
>   Grunthos the Flatulent, of his poem,
>   Ode to a Small Lump of Green Putty I
>   Found in My Armpit One Midsummer
>   Morning, four of his audience members
>   died of internal hemorrhaging, and the
>   president of the Mid-Galactic Arts
>   Nobbling Council, survived by gnawing
>   one of his own legs off... The very
>   worst poetry in the universe died
>   along with its creator, Paula Nancy
>   Millstone Jennings of Sussex, in the
>   destruction of the planet Earth.

At least the destruction of our planet was good for something.

Answer (score 16):

It's worth noting that originally, in the radio series, the creator of the worst poetry in the universe was Paul Neil Milne Johnston of Redbridge. However, this was actually a real person (that Adams went to school with, IIRC), and for legal reasons the name was changed to the obviously made-up Paula Nancy Millstone Jennings for all subsequent versions.

Comment: On one version, the name is mangled, clearly while in the process of legal proceedings. I suspect Paul Johnstone was the inspiration for this entire Vogon poetry section, which he should be proud of.

Answer (score 7):

The second worst is, as quoted in other answers: The Azgoths of Kria.

The worst, according to the *Radio Series* rather than the book was: Paul Neil Milne Johnston of Redbridge, who perished along with his creation in the destruction of the Earth. [This is described at the end of Fit the First.]